# How can I send dmesg printout to ftrace subsystem?

Tags: linux, kernel, dmesg, ftrace

How can I send `dmesg` printout to `ftrace` subsystem?

I like correlate the `dmesg` msg with the functions call `graph` in `ftrace`.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it:

```
cd /sys/kernel/debug/
echo 1 > events/printk/enable
```